# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "phptest01072003@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, laravel-8

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "phptest01072003@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials mv24-20020a17090b199800b001d954837197sm10565041pjb.22 - gsmtp ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials mv24-20020a17090b199800b001d954837197sm10565041pjb.22 - gsmtp ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials mv24-20020a17090b199800b001d954837197sm10565041pjb.22 - gsmtp ".

**mail code:-**

```
public function html_email() {
        $data = array('name'=>"HJ KING");
        Mail::send('layout.forgotpasswordmodel', $data, function($message) {
           $message->to(session('forgotemail'), 'HII, '.session('forgotfname'))->subject
              ('ForgotPassword');
              $message->from('xyz@gmail.com','HJ KING');
        });
      //   echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
      // return redirect('forgotpassword');
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
          'email' => 'MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY',
      ]);
     }
```

**.Env file:-**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=phptest01072003@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Yeah, no need to post the error message 3 times, have you used an app password? Or allow less secure apps? [App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833), [Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Comment: yes but now less secure app is gone from google mail, password i provided in file is correct

Comment: Hmm learned something new, you created an app password?

Comment: no i want to send a random new generated password in mail

Comment: Yes sure, the mail send a new password to the user. However the app password need is for the gmail account you're using, which needs that specific password. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Answer (score 0):

at the end

I connect my Laravel app into Gmail

by getting password from app password in security

by turning on two-step verification on my second Gmail account